# ScrollToTtem is not smooth

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I am using a colletionview images to scroll images horizontally. I am getting the index using didselectitem from the first collection view and through segue transition, I am using the selected index to pick the images from the array in the secondcollectionview.

Since I am using , ScrollToItem, when I am clicking, image[5], it takes me to the 6th image after skipping the first 5 images. Everything works, but the problem is, the transition is not smooth. I could see the first 5 images sliding for a fraction of second and its not cool. How to get a seamless transition while scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me with smooth transition (Horizontally) in a CollectionView. Please check your scrollToItem method.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let nextItem: IndexPath = IndexPath(item: 4, section: 0)
        self.collectionCatlogue.scrollToItem(at: nextItem, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
```

If this things not works for you then please share your code.